# Apache. I get a SSL 60 error self-signed certificate error. I need a higher CA I think

Tags: apache, ssl, x509certificate

I'm running an Apache 2 server. I have generated a private-key/certificate pair but web browser requests don't trust the security so I think I need to generate the pair from a higher authority. I have been using the openssl command but I don't truly know what constitutes the higher authority or what its private key is or where it is in my apache installation. I presume it is the apache organisation itself. Help, I'm desperate and no expert!

Comment: That is of course not possible. (If it was, I would go and “self-sign” me a certificate for Google or Facebook right now, and make it look like this was genuine ...) If you want that, then you can’t self-sign it, but need to get it issued by an external, trusted entity in the first place. But most browsers allow you to add an exception to trust self-signed certificates.

Comment: I think the likelihood is that the Apache server certificate and key that it came with, must have been fine in the first place.#